# Using functions in PHP?

Tags: php, function

How do I simply call a function by using PHP?

Say I have created:

```
function sam(){
 echo "Hello World!;
 exit();
}
```

How would I initiate the function?

Comment: Honestly, Sam, you may want to pick up a PHP book and read up some before asking for help on sites like these. This is about as basic as it gets.

Comment: @Gumbo: I edited out the " you added to his code; if that's how he posted it and there's answers referring to the missing quote, then it takes everything out of context to fix the mistake in the question.

Comment: I don't see any problem asking extremely basic questions here. I don't think we should discriminate against beginners here.

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not necessarily 'advanced' programming question. Sam's question was on topic and I don't think it should be downvoted because it's an easy answer.

Comment: It is a big problem. This question have their answer everywhere in the web, so you don't need another place to be. At the contrary, SO allows you to solve problem you have usually trouble to deal with or to discover things. If you let questions like this one to be asked, then you will add a lot of noise in SO and the interesting stuff will be lost in the mess (while the basic stuff won't be best answered as anywhere else). Finally SO would become as interesting as any fora in the Web.

Comment: I didn't downvote this and I'm all for beginner questions here - I just got done defending another one of his questions when someone said it was too simple - my advice was more towards his own personal journey towards being a better programmer. Coming here to ask questions like these displays a severe lack of understanding basic programming concepts. In the spirit of that, he's probably best served reading a book to get an idea of how languages work, instead of generating Yet More Bad PHP Code.

Answer (score 15):

**Is this a trick question?**

First thing I notice is you are missing a quote:

```
function sam(){ echo "Hello World!; exit(); }
```

.. should be ..

```
function sam(){ echo "Hello World!"; exit(); }
```

*(I see you fixed your post after I mentioned the above by adding the quote).*

Next, in your case, the function echo's the result, and then **exits the entire script** (*it doesn't just exit the function as you may be assuming*), so not much you can do with that other than this:

```
<?php

function sam(){ 
  echo "Hello World!"; 
  exit(); 
}

sam();
// anything here on down will not execute or render!

?>
```

However, if your function was more real-world, like this:

```
function sam() {
  return "Hello World!";
}
```

.. then you could do any of these (and more) ..

```
$s = sam();
echo $s;
$s = "Say it: " . sam();
echo $s;
```

Answer (score 13):

Like this -

```
sam();
```

Comment: very well put. straight to the point! +1

Answer (score 8):

Read [the PHP manual about functions](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php). And note that [`exit`](http://docs.php.net/exit) will not just exit the function but the whole script. So nothing else will be executed after this call.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i suppose:

`sam();`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

sam();

?>
```

help yourself to php.net

Comment: This is a lame answer, but it was honestly what first came to my mind when I read the question. People need to go to a little effort to find answers in their language's official documentation before they give up and decide to take it to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started using OOP techniques in PHP, and one simple bit of information that I found hard to find online was that if you want to call your function as part of the object you need to use `$this->functionName();`

i.e.

```
class newInstance {
    function helloWorld(){
      echo 'Hello world';
    }
}

$object = new newInstance();
$object->helloWorld;
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the other answers here, I think your intention for using exit() is actually satisfied by the [return construct](http://php.net/return). More info on [returning values](http://us.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php).

However, in your example there is no reason to have it since PHP functions return void automatically once the function ends and no other return value has been specified.

An example where you would want to use return to stop a function from continuing:

```
function foo($bar) {
  if ($bar < 10) {
    return;
  }

  return $bar * 10;
}
print foo(1); // Prints nothing
print foo(20); // Prints 200
```

I couldn't tell you what real-world application this particular example has but it shows a useful situation where you may want to cut a function short.

Another example showing that return is not needed in simple functions:

```
function foo($bar) {
  print $bar * 10;
}

foo(20); // Prints 200
print foo(20); // Also prints 200, but since the function does not return anything, the print statement on this line does nothing.
```

You may also want to checkout the [PHP.net manual section on Functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php). Hope this helps.